# How can I pass data from django to react at render time

Tags: reactjs, django

The question is fairly simple. I need to pass data from django to a react component. In django, I have a json object being dumped:

```
class PulseHome(TemplateView):
    template_name = "pulse_murasa/pulse_home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        efestos_queryset = Efesto.objects.filter(deleted=False).order_by('-id')
        efestos = EfestoSerializer(efestos_queryset, many=True)
        context['efestos'] = json.dumps(efestos.data)   // THIS IS WHAT MATTERS
        return context
```

In the html, I get the data like this, it logs correctly:

```
<script id="efestos-data" type="application/json">
    {{ efestos|safe }}
</script>
<script>
    const efestosData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('efestos-data').textContent);   // THIS IS WHAT MATTERS
    console.log(efestosData);
</script>
<script src="{% static 'js/main.de0443a6.js' %} "> </script>
```

Then, in my React index.js file, I try to get the data but it is undefined:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import EfestoComponent from './components/pulseHome';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const efesto_objects = window.efestosData;   // THIS IS WHAT MATTERS
console.log("efesto_objects: ", efesto_objects);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <EfestoComponent objects={efesto_objects}/>
);
```

I guess it has something to do with timing. I could try to tie everything to a `DOMContentLoaded` listener, but I wonder if there is a standard way to achieve this.

Comment: https://adamj.eu/tech/2022/10/06/how-to-safely-pass-data-to-javascript-in-a-django-template/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jimmy Pells comment was useful, as the documentation points to the use of the keyword `defer` in script tags.

However, the problem was that this line was not working:

```
const efesto_objects = window.efestosData;
```

The variable is not accessible by index.js at the time of execution.
Changing it to this solved it:

```
const efestosData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('efestos-data').textContent);
```